# web2py error : Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, web2py

I've been googling for days trying to find a straight answer for why this is happening, but can't find anything useful. I have a web2py application that simply reads a database and makes some requests to a REST api. It is a healthcheck monitor so it refreshes itself every minute. There are about 20 or so users at any given time. Here is the error I'm seeing very consistently in the log file:

```
ERROR:Rocket.Errors.Port8080:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/apps/web2py/gluon/rocket.py", line 562, in listen
    sock = self.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "/opt/apps/web2py/gluon/rocket.py", line 506, in wrap_socket
    ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 342, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 121, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 281, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Based on some googling the most promising piece of information is that someone is trying to connect through a firewall and so it is killing the connection, however I don't understand why it's taking the actual application down. The process is still running, but no one can connect and I have to restart web2py.

I will be very appreciative of any input here. I'm beyond frustration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common source of `Connection reset by peer` errors is that the remote client decides he doesn't want to contact you anymore, and cancels the interaction (with [`shutdown`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shutdown)/an `RST` packet). This happens if the user navigates to a different page while the site is loading.

In your case, the remote host gave up on the connection even before you got to read or write anything on it. With the current web2py, this should only output the warning you're seeing, and not terminate anything.

If you have the current web2py, the error of not being able to connect is unrelated to these error messages. If you have an old version of web2py, you should update.

Comment: Well at least now I know that the application stopping is not caused by those errors. Thank you!